# Red cross on Eclipse project name

Tags: eclipse

I imported a project in Eclipse. But it shows a red cross on the project name. It does not show any errors in any of the internal files so I am confused where the actual problem is.. It looks like this Eclipse error:

[image: Eclipse error]

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is most likely to be found in the Problems view (use Window -> Show View).

It can be missing Jars (referenced jar isn't there), or a lib in the build path
(right-click on your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path),
or other.

You might be able to "solve" it by deleting the messages in the Problems tab and
re-building the project. Select the project and click on the menu bar
"Project -> Clean...", select your project and okay.

There can be other reasons for this problem.
Post your Problems view if the above advice does not solve the problem.